# C# IntPtr as a member of a class, cannot delete pointer

Tags: c#, pointers, free

Hello coders out there,

I have a question about C# pointer. I do not know what to do to get the code running.

So, in my WPF project there is this Class `MainViewModel` which contains one IntPtr.

```
private IntPtr m_context;
```

This context is filled when loading Data from an C-Interface (the interface does a "return new class_name()"). I call it like that:

```
this.m_context = interface_context_create();
```

When being used, I want to delete the context. This is also an interface method. I would expect it to call like this **in the same method as the creation above (!!)**:

```
unsafe
{
    interface_context_free(&this.m_context);
}
```

The `interface_context_free(..)` gets a class_name** on the c-interface-side, so thats why I need to use &. The interface on my C# side is correct, since my `test1()` method (see below) does create and free correctly.

This gives at `interface_context_free(&this.m_context);` following error:

**CS:0212 you can only take the address of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement initializer**

If I declare it like this, then it works absolutely fine!!!:

```
public void test1()
{
  IntPtr iptr = interface_context_create();

  unsafe
  {
    interface_context_free(&iptr);
  }
}
```

How can I free `m_context` and where is the difference between the two scenarios??

Comment: Does `interface_context_free` really take a pointer to a pointer? If it does, why? That looks pretty suspicious to begin with

Comment: @harold yes it does. Its a used interface in our company so there is no chance to change it

Comment: Not even to `ref IntPtr`? That would still be compatible with the same native code, but makes the C# side easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a quite simple fix.

The reason you cannot do `&this.m_context` is because that variable is not fixed in memory. As such, while you have an address to that variable floating around in unmanaged space, GC may kick in and move that variable somewhere else rendering that address invalid. This could happen if the object instance containing the field `m_context` survives a garbage collection cycle and thus gets promoted to a new generation, and thus moved into a new memory location.

The fix is quite simple: copy the IntPtr value into a local variable first. Variables on the stack are not moved around and taking their address is fine, as long as you don't let that address live past the scope of the variable.

So instead of this:

```
unsafe
{
    interface_context_free(&this.m_context);
}
```

just do this:

```
unsafe
{
    IntPtr temp = this.m_context;
    interface_context_free(&temp);
}
```

Note that if the reason the `interface_context_free` function takes a pointer to a variable is that it not only frees the object referenced from the variable but also modifies the variable content itself by for instance setting it to point to `null`, you would have to copy the modified temporary variable back into the field:

```
unsafe
{
    IntPtr temp = this.m_context;
    interface_context_free(&temp);
    this.m_context = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is relate with garbadge collector. You should tag field as non-moving for GC.

```
fixed (void* myIntPtr = &intPtr)
{
    interface_context_free(myIntPtr);
}
```

Details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement

Comment: in this case, `intPtr` is still not fixed so you still cannot take its address. You will have to fix the object containing the IntPtr I believe but this is down a rabbit hole I haven't delved.

Comment: unfortunately, this does not work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71221649/18091434 did it

Comment: @niconice, which issue you have with my example?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen first example at MSDN ref showing how field of class can be fixed.

Comment: i copy-pasted that into my code, then changed intPtr to this.m_context (this is my variable that I have). After that I got an error that void* cannot be converted to IntPtr.